# Reimplementing getline function for my own String class

Tags: c++, string

I am kind of new to C++, and I wrote my own `String` class, but I would really need the `getline` function to work for file manipulation. I've written the function as below:

```cpp
std::istream& getlineString(std::istream& is, String& str, char delim) {
  char ch;
  str = "";
  int i = 0;
  while (is.get(ch) && ch != delim) {
    str[i] = ch;
    i++;
  }
  return is;
}
```

And tried running it like this:

```cpp
String s;
getlineString(cin, s, '\n');
cout << s;
```

It all worked fine (it let me give an input string with whitespaces in them ex: `"Stack overflow"`), but it gave me an error message in my terminal with g++ compiler, without printing out the string:

```
Stack overflow
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
make: *** [main] Error 3
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that `str[i]` is invalid, unless your implementation of `String::operator[]` resizes internal buffer if you call it with index out of range. We can't tell without seeing more of `String` class. Using debugger could help you solve the issue yourself.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen  Here are the indexing operators, they seem to be working fine tho
https://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IYG38

Comment: When adding details, rather [edit] your question than provide it in comments as a link. But yeah, you see the exception you implemented yourself. Your `operator[]` is throwing `"String: indexelesi hiba"`, because after `str = "";` your `String` has length `0`. You probably need some sort of `push_back` method that is capable of resizing your `String` or some other way of dynamically changing its size.